# What is the simple explanation for this nested loop

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
main(){    
        int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
        int nums[10];
        time_t t;

        srand(time(&t));

        for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++){
          nums[ctr] = (rand() % 99) + 1;
        }

        // Now list the array as it currently is before sorting
        puts("\nHere is the list before the sort:");
        for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
          printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
        }

        // Sort the array
        for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++) {
          didSwap = 0; //Becomes 1 (true) if list is not yet ordered
          for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++) { // << I dont uunderstand this nested loop ?               
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
              temp = nums[inner];
              nums[inner] = nums[outer];
              nums[outer] = temp;
              didSwap = 1;
            }
          }

          if (didSwap == 0) {
            break;
          }
        }

        // Now list the array as it currently is after sorting
        puts("\nHere is the list after the sort:");
        for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
          printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
        }

   return(0);
}
```

I really struggle sometimes with codes, this code from a book which teaches C programming for newbies like me it sorts random numbers from the lower value in the top to the greatest value in the bottom. I came across the nested loop trying to figure out how it works I still not sure how does it work. Why the value of the variable `outter` is assigned to the variable inner ? I understand the first loop repeats the nested loop 8 times because of  `outter < 9`, this makes no sense to me since the array consists of 10 elements. I'm confused! so `outter` should repeats the nested loop 9 times I guess ? maybe ? it could be !

```
for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++) { // << I don't understand this nested loop ? 
  if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
    temp = nums[inner];
    nums[inner] = nums[outer];
    nums[outer] = temp;
    didSwap = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: My first suggestion - indent the code so you can read it better.

Comment: Looks like a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the code in the nested loop says:

```
loop from the first element to the next-to-last element:

   loop from the current value of the outer loop, to the last element, 
     looking for a smaller value than the one I am looking at in the outer loop.
     if you find a smaller value, swap it into place. 
   if you didn't swap anything during this inner loop, exit; << BUG??
```

**First off, I think the algorithm has a bug:** the `didswap=0` condition at the end of the inner loop only means that the current position was smaller than values below it; unless I misread something, it does not mean that the whole list is sorted, so I think that is broken. (example: if you define your list so that the smallest element starts in position zero, I think this whole thing exits without swapping anything, no matter how the rest of the list is sorted. But, `didswap` is an optimization: the loops will terminate without the `did swap` flag anyway, so I'd take it out altogether for now and consider the main algorithm.

**But let's look past that to understand what the rest of the code is doing:** `outer = inner` makes sure the inner loop starts where the outer loop is currently. (so: start with the 0th element. Loop from element 0 to element 10, and if you find an element smaller than the current element 0, swap it with element 0 and keep searching. Once the inner loop gets to element 10, you know that element 0 must be the smallest element in the whole list, because you compared with every other element in the list. So now, we look at the element in position 1 (outer=1) and compare with every element from position 1 to position 10, looking for an element smaller than the one at position 1, and if we find it, we swap the elements. So when we finish the second pass of the inner loop, we know that the element at position 1 is the second-smallest element in the array. Then we move on to looking at the third element, etc.

Note: there is a slight inefficiency here: you could start with `inner = outer+1`, since it will never be true that nums[i] < nuns[i], so the first iteration of the inner loop is wasted. But honestly, this type of sort is so painfully inefficient, that this change is in the noise.  There are many more efficient sort algorithms, which I'm sure are covered later in your text.

Comment: very nice, but I encourage the OP to learn how to use a debugger, develop small test files, and then run the code, watching values of variables change. Good luck to all!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort to answer my question I appreciate it. I thought at first about {inner = outer+1}, but the book which I'm reading to learn C is basic for new programmers and they mentioned they're books in sorting data this is very primitive method just to teach newbies.

Comment: I tested the code and it works pretty well, perhaps there's a mistake in this posted code.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the value of the variable `outter` is assigned to the variable `inner` ?

To  iterate the inner loop from  `outter` to `9`. This is because all the elements from `nums[0]` to `nums[outer-1]` get already sorted.

> I understand the first loop repeats the nested loop `8` times because of `outter < 9`, this makes no sense to me since the array consists of `10` elements.

The outer loop should be iterated only `9` times. This is because no need to sort the last element `num[9]`. It came to last of the array after sorting the `9` elements.